# How to execute observable in parallel threads

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, rx-java

I have Observable called messages which contains several messages.I want to process these messages at the same time.How can i do this using rxJava??

messages.(code to execute observable items parallel).subscribe(msg->process(msg))

(If the observable contains five different messages then I need to process these five messages in five seperate threads)

Comment: This sounds like a bad mix of multithread and NIO reactive models.  Are you sure this will be a good thing?

Comment: Subscribe 5 Observers to the Observable ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to stay in the `Observable` world, you can `flatMap` each element with `subscribeOn` and computation you want in parallel:

```
Observable.range(1, 10)
.flatMap(v -> 
    Observable.fromCallable(() -> compute(v))
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation)
)
.subscribe(e -> { }, Throwable::printStackTrace);
```

Comment: and if you want the results to maintain the given order, then you can use `concatMapEager` instead of `flatMap` and maintain the concurrency.

Answer (score 0):

Run single thread that "observe" your messages, and dispatch every message that it contains to new message handling task (eg simple `Runnable`) that is submitted to some sort of [workers thread pool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html).

Here you will find simple how-to: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html